# Laravel Validation check array size min and max

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I just need to check in Laravel validation that an array contains minimum 2 values and maximum 4 values. Is there any default validation rule can be used for this ? The `size` element checks for exact size match and the other rules likes `min` and `max` are for strings, digits and file size.

Comment: I do not believe there currently is a validation rule for this. You can however create [a custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: which laravel version do you use?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Ah Ok. You need to make your own validator check. The default size validator only checks the value and not min/max.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A little bit late:

```
return [
    "ticket_photo" => ["required","array","min:2","max:4"], // validate an array contains minimum 2 elements and maximum 4 
    "ticket_photo.*" => ["required","mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif"], // and each element must be a jpeg or jpg or png or gif file 
];
```

laravel 5.6

Answer (score 51):

You can use `between`.
.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-between

For example:

```
'users' => 'required|array|between:2,4'
```

It is not explicitly stated in the docs, but it works with arrays, just like `size`.

For more details, read [validating array lengths in Laravel](https://arievisser.com/blog/validating-array-lengths-in-laravel/)

Comment: Now It is in Documentation too 5.6