# How to validate an array without keys in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: laravel, validation, testing, lumen

For testing, I want to use the validator method to validate the size and minimum size of this passwordsArray:

```
    array:9 [
      0 => "password 0"
      1 => "password 1"
      2 => "password 2"
      3 => "password 3"
      4 => "password 4"
      5 => "password 5"
    ]
```

I'm trying something like:

```
$validator = Validator::make($passwordsArray, [
            'passwordsArray' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        if( $validator->passes() ){
            $this->assertTrue(true);

        }else{

            $this->assertTrue(false);
        }
```

I'm getting this error:

*Failed asserting that false is true.*

Help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342411/laravel-validation-check-array-size-min-and-max

Answer (score 0):

Your `$passwordsArray` needs to have an element named `passwordsArray` which unless you've omitted from your example, it does not appear to have.

```
$passwordsArray= [
    'passwordsArray' => [
        'password 0',
        'password 1',
        'password 2',
        'password 3',
        'password 4',
        'password 5',
    ]
];

$validator = Validator::make($passwordsArray, [
    'passwordsArray' => ['required', 'min:6']
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd('Failed validation');
}

dd('Passed validation');
```

[Working example here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/jolly-wood-qapx-bll8r)

Comment: Thanks for answering. My real case doesn't have that element, that's why I asked if existed a way to implement it without it

Comment: Do you have the option to alter the input array from you request object to add the element, or create a new array from the request array?

Comment: Yes, that's what i got to do. Create a new array $passwordsArray = ['passwordsArray' => $passwordsArray].
Then use your approach